# While loop goes on forever despite condition being met

Tags: python

My while loop is supposed to end once each letter in display is not an underscore.

However despite display updating to remove all underscores. The loop keeps going on, and I can't figure out why.

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_length = len(chosen_word)


print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"


guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

def check_letter():
  for position in range(word_length):
      letter = chosen_word[position]
      if letter == guess:
          display[position] = letter
  print(display)

check_letter()

for item in display:
  while item == "_":
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    check_letter()

print("You've Won")
```

Comment: You don't change the value of `item` in the `while` so the `while` never ends.

Comment: I think you want `if`, not `while`.

Comment: I can't understand the intended logic of the code. The point of `check_letter` is to replace *every letter in the `display`* that matches a particular `guess`, right? So then why would we follow up by *looping over the letters* and asking for a new guess *at each position*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your code for much longer than I thought I would.  The problem is subtle.

The issue with your code is that `item` never changes it's value (despite the for loop).  And that's why the problem is subtle - the  for loop (`for item in display:`) only iterates once because the while loop it contains is endless.  The while loop is endless is because nothing in the while loop changes the value of `item`.

All that said, I can see why you are asking here at SO.  Here's a bit of code that eliminates the for loop for just a while loop.  I've eliminated the `item` variable - it doesn't change anyway.  Rather, the condition that keeps us in the loop is there is still an underscore in the `display` variable.

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_length = len(chosen_word)


print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"


guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

def check_letter():
  for position in range(word_length):
      letter = chosen_word[position]
      if letter == guess:
          display[position] = letter
  print(display)

check_letter()

while '_' in display:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    check_letter()

print("You've Won")
```

Answer (score 0):

item is a copy of your display element. This may be what you want

```
for i in range(word_length):
  while display[i] == "_":
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    check_letter()
```

Comment: This makes sense so because the function is called within the while loop. The item variable never gets updated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this logic is great, but I guess it works.  The while loop  will now only exit when the user has correctly guessed the first letter.  The while loop will then get stuck again on the next letter that the end user hasn't guessed yet.  Ultimately, this gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_length = len(chosen_word)
display = []

print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"


guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

def check_letter(display):
  for position in range(word_length):
      letter = chosen_word[position]
      if letter == guess:
          display[position] = letter
  print(display)

check_letter(display)

for item in display:
  while item == "_":
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    check_letter(display)
    if (''.join([str(elem) for elem in display]) == chosen_word) :
        break


print("You've Won")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).